# Flying to South Korea when passport includes maternal surname but ticket does not

Tags: air-travel, passports, tickets, paperwork, south-korea

I am flying to South Korea from Miami, Florida. My passport says my name like "Patricia Rivera Ruiz" (my dad's last name and mom’s last name, since I am hispanic), but my plane ticket says "Patricia Rivera". Will this be an issue when at the airport?

Answer (score 5):

As long as all the parts that are on the ticket are on the passport, you'll be fine. I'm in the same case as you, and never had problems, either in Korea or elsewhere.

Someone I know is in a similar, but more accute, case: his first name is 4 words long, last name 6, and he picked 2 each for everyday things. He sometimes has to point things out, but never was denied boarding or entrance in a country.